# How to stop mysql, run a command and start mysql without having the container stop running?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a container that, when starting up, loads some data into a database and it all works great.

I now want to delete the directory that the source data files are in at the end of this process using `rm -rf /mysrc`.

As part of the process (inside the Dockerfile) I have given mysql:mysql permissions over the src directory I use to load everything from because if I don't it has problems with loading the data (via a third party script that does the loading) and blows up.

When the time comes to clear the src directory and call `rm -rf /mysrc` I get a 'Permission Denied' error BUT the contents of /mysrc are deleted while the directory remains.

If I try and `chown root:root /mysrc` I get 'Operation Not Permitted' error and the directory remains of course.

The fact that the directory sticks around but the files are removed makes me think that the mysqld must have a handle on the folder when I go to delete it.

If I try to stop the mysql service (and free any handles on the folder) from either the container via bash OR the script, the container stops.

How can I remove this directory (and contents)? How can I restart the mysql service inside the container without killing the container?

Comment: What's so special about this directory?

Comment: It is just a staging folder for the third party script (*.sh), *.sql scripts and data files (over 1 GB). I have my own script that is inside of /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d that launches the third party script. I know I can bash in after all is said and done and remove the directory but I would like to do it as part of the container start up process once the load is done.

Comment: So you didn't make it a volume or something?

Comment: Not this time, the db is pretty much for read only purposes and for now not a production db. I am using it right now for looking things up while I develop. I could make it a volume (and have) but decided to just redo it as all self contained for now.